# Shopify node backend- frontend communication

Tags: shopify

I am really new in shopify app development.

I have an allready a working app what i have created with next.JS (I have worked with node/express too)

I just would like to create a connection between my frontend and backend with a simple endpoint.

It means i send a get request and i receive something nonsense. The main goal would be that is the backend can communicate with the frontend.

I have created a git repo too.: https://github.com/akospaska/shopify-outofthebox

The app has been created with shopify-cli

In my pages folder there is an index.js file, where my frontend "lives".

I have created (or i think ) 2 differend endpoints.

1. pages/api/test   endpoint: "/test"
2. server/server.js  endpoint: "/test2"

When i call the endpoints i get an error.

I have read the documentation but it just makes me confused.

How should i authenticate between my backend and frontend exactly?

Thank you for your help Guys in advance.

Comment: Was checking if you manage to progress or find a solution for this? I'm actually trying to achieve something similar to what you've got here, however, facing the same thing with the simple endpoints showing as error.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoints aren't pages, they are routes on your express app.

Here is a related question with answer:

[Node backend communication between react frontend and node backend | Shopify related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73446678/node-backend-communication-between-react-frontend-and-node-backend-shopify-rel)

Here is a checklist for you how to set up an endpoint (POST):

1.) Navigate to your index.js file in the /web directory

2.) Insert this code:

```
app.post("/api/test", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      res.status(201).send(response);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
  });
}
```

app.post() sets up a route in your project.

3.) Navigate to your index.jsx file in /pages directory and insert this code (I set up a callback when a form submit button is clicked):

```
 const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    (body) => {
      (async () => {
        const parsedBody = body;
        
        
        const response = await fetch("/api/test?shop=YOUR_SHOP_URL, {
          method: "POST",
          body: parsedBody
        });
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log("Success");
        }
      })();
      return { status: "success" };
    },
   []
  );

<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

</Form>
```

it should call this API endpoint. So now you communicate with an API endpoint.

Maybe I could help you with my answer!

Comment: With the shopify CLI tool we can create an aout of the box nodejs/react application.
In that template file the connection between the frontend/backend already solved.
Btw with the graphql endpoint too.